# MySQL Trigger AFTER INSERT to auto-increment a column

Tags: mysql

I'm sort of a newbie with MySQL and DBs in general so bear with me :)

I have a table - tblfolders which has a field 'barcodeID' which is an INT that I need incremented by 1 each time a new row is inserted into the table. I can't make this an auto-increment field because I already have my 'id' field auto-incrementing.

I tried doing this with an AFTER INSERT trigger but I keep getting an error: "Can't update table 'tblfolders' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger."

Any suggestions on how I can auto-increment this field on an insert into my table?

Thanks!

Comment: I am really afraid about triggers :) can't you do something different?

Comment: what about making the barcodeId a foreign key to a barcode table, that has an autoincrement primary key...

Comment: lol yeah I read a little about triggers yesterday and got excited, but they seem like more trouble than they're worth - at least for what I'm trying to do at my low level of expertise :)

Comment: Adding another table is a good idea... Maybe I'm crazy, but why can't a table have two auto-incrementing fields...?

Comment: here's a good answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3467/mysql-why-is-auto-increment-limited-to-just-primary-keys

Comment: Why don't you post your table schemas and the trigger? It looks like you're doing the trigger on the wrong table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
use the auto_increment and then format it using php with something like sprintf of printf:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $numberOfZerosINeed = 10-strlen($row['id']);
    $formated_id =   sprintf(" %010s ",  $row['id']); // zero-padding works on strings too
    $row['barcode_id']=$formated_id;
    $all_rows[]=$row;
}
```

at this points it's as if you had a column barcode_id with the formated AUTO_INCREMENT integer!

**OLD ANSWER**
you can use the programming language to do something like after insert, its hard to say what is best, you should describe what you want to do  and if you are using anything like php, why does the auto_increment itself not give you the data you need? in php you could do something like an after insert:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblfolders (id, othervales) VALUES ('{$id}', '{$othervalues}') ");
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query("UPDATE tblfolders SET barcode_id='".($old_barcode_id+1)." WHERE id={$last_id} LIMIT 1 ");
```

Comment: Well, I could use the existing auto_increment field BUT I need this 'barcodeId' field to be left-padded with zeros so that it is always 10 characters long. BTW, I'm using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

What about making the `barcodeId` a foreign key to a barcode table, that has an autoincrement primary key?